# Issue retrieving Object using React

Tags: reactjs, object, scope

I am trying to reach `arrival` from an object using React without success. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

JS

```
const buses =
  [{ "id": 1, "busNumber": "55", "arrival": "1 min"}, { "id": 2, "busNumber": "13", "arrival": "1 min"}, { "id": 3, "busNumber": "55", "arrival": "3 min"}]

const List = ({items, each}) =>

  <div className = "panel panel-default">
  <div className = "panel-heading"><h2>Bus stop</h2></div>
    <div className = "panel-body">   

      <ul className = "list-group">{items.map((item, key) =>
        <ListItem key = {key} item = {each(item)} />)}</ul>

    </div>
  </div>

const ListItem = ({item, arrival}) =>
  <li className = "list-group-item"><span className = "badge">{arrival}</span>{item}</li>


const Item = ({busNumber}) =>
  <div>{busNumber}</div>

ReactDOM.render(<List items={buses} each={Item} />, document.querySelector('#main'))
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/diegooriani/pen/QgYgvb?editors=1000)

I am new to React, so please forgive me for basic mistakes. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the arrival value in `ListItem` that's why.

Use this:

```
<ListItem key={key} item={each(item)} arrival={item.arrival}/>
```

Working **[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgvLRV?editors=1010)**.

Comment: Thank you Mayank!

Comment: Can I abuse of your kindness and ask why am I getting errors in the console? Uncaught ReferenceError: arrival is not defined and Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined

Comment: sorry didn't get you, when you are getting those errors? check the codepen it is working properly.